# "unable to load kernel module nvidia.ko" BUT "modprobe -r nouveau" = FATAL (not found)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nouveau, blacklist

Im lost. I've tried many things and even broke my installation. This is a new installation, which I'm more carefull with.

I've blacklisted nouveau, and It seems it's not loaded as "modprobe -r nouveau" returns FATAL.

Can you show me the way? Ask for any file/output you need, I'll give everything.

Reason to install Nvidia official driver:

- Unity 3D environment + Performance.
- Additional drivers shows no other options.
- I believe it's better.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Graphic card is: GeForce FX 5200

Driver trying to install: NVIDIA-Linux-x86-173.14.39-pkg1.run

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Install the deb package using apt-get. The version available from apt-get is up to date and is the same version as the downloaded version from nvidia

Execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-173 
sudo reboot
```

---

Edit #2

To verify the version available from apt-get, run the following command

```
apt-cache search nvidia-173
```

if apt-get does not have the newest version, here' a link to the deb download for the latest version available from the "proposed" repo:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/160095725/nvidia-173_173.14.39-0ubuntu0.0.1_i386.deb
```

After downloading, to install it run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo chmod +x nvidia-173_173.14.39-0ubuntu0.0.1_i386.deb
sudo gdebi nvidia-173_173.14.39-0ubuntu0.0.1_i386.deb
```

Comment: You must run the nvidia installation with NO xsession running. This MUST be run from a text session.

Comment: I know. I've run it in the Ctrl+Alt+F1 text session. There I've stoped lightdm before running the installation: 'sudo service lightdm stop'.

Comment: Okay good, did you run the other commands? If so, what errors do you receive?

Comment: The installation starts, but gives me an error later "unable to load module kernel 'nvidia.ko' ".

Comment: @yinon I've included the instructions for installing the apt-get version for you.

Comment: I prfer using the downloaded version, than the suggested package. Anyway I can make the installation finish successfully?

Comment: @yinon the apt-get version is the SAME version as the downloaded one `apt-cache search nvidia-173`: nvidia-173 - NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 173.14.39

Comment: @yinon see Edit #2

Comment: @yinon there's a bug with that downloaded nvidia version and 12.04 and I'm not aware of a fix but the .deb is available.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Just tell me, what the difference between the 173, 173-updates etc.

And if I change my graphic card after the OS is installed, should I do something like removing the wrong installed one or that installing the new one will remove it anyway?

And why do 'Additional Drivers' shows no driver to install?

Comment: OUTPUT of 'apt-cache search nvidia-173':

nvidia-173 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library [end]
nvidia-173-dev -  קבצי פיתוח של מנהל ההתקן הבינארי של NVIDIA עבור Xorg (Translation: Develop files of Nvidia's Binary driver for Xorg) [end]
nvidia-173-updates - Transitional package for nvidia-173 [end]
nvidia-173-updates-dev - Transitional package for nvidia-173-dev

I'll download the driver from your link (Latest version). I'll tell you if it succeeded.

Comment: I've installed. I think I'll reboot now.

Comment: My OS broke. I reinstalled because after rebooting the system loaded into low graphic mode and I couldn't get to the GUI.

Im afraid to try it again. But maybe it's because of my blacklist(s) ?

Comment: I've also saw that this driver my be not compatible with new kernels. What should I do?